# Regex.Match Uppercase

Tags: regex

Is there any way when using .net's Regex.Match() to work out if a string only contains capitals?

I am working in an application (so I don't have access to the code) which allows me to see if a field matches a certain regex pattern (using Regex.Match() behind the scene). So I want to use this to work out if the string is only capitals.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use /^[A-Z]+$/

Comment: @JGrice That would work for ASCII only.  `\p{Upper}`, for Regex engines that support it, will work for 1483 upper-cased letters across many alphabets.  Your suggestion only misses 1457 of them. ;)  That begs the question: @Richard, do you need to support Unicode, or only ASCII?

Comment: @DavidO does .net Regex.match() support \p{Upper} ? Couldn't find any documentation on it in the quick search I did.

Comment: Shocking... just found out from the provider that the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is set, hence why nothing has worked. Sorry everyone. But for anyone else in the future I'll set Jeffrey's answer as the right one.

Comment: @JGrice http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx  I think that demonstrates that `\p{ name }` is supported, where "name" can be standard Unicode properties.

Comment: It is not `\p{Upper}`, as stated in my answer, you would use `\p{Lu}`

Comment: Yes, `\p{Lu}` supports 1441 characters, and is probably what the doctor orders. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this as your match string for only capital letters and no special characters, including space.

```
^[A-Z]*$
```

To allow for special characters(only contains characters not lower case):

```
^[^a-z]*$
```

Comment: Shocking... just found out from the provider that the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is set, hence why nothing has worked. Sorry everyone. But for anyone else in the future I'll set Jeffrey's answer as the right one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regex. This will match any uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.

```
^\p{Lu}+$
```

Or you can simply match only uppercase letter characters.

```
^[A-Z]+$
```